# Extract img src from JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I use blogger as my blogging platform. In my blog homepage, I want to use slider as my post thumbnail when my post contain more than 1 image inside. So, I create a JSON request inside all post, and the results look like this:

```
// API callback
extract({
    "version": "1.0",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "entry": {
        "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
        "xmlns$blogger": "http://schemas.google.com/blogger/2008",
        "xmlns$georss": "http://www.georss.org/georss",
        "xmlns$gd": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005",
        "xmlns$thr": "http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0",
        "id": {
            "$t": "tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-8885963640212113245.post-2877822832429210498"
        },
        "published": {
            "$t": "2014-10-23T21:36:00.004+07:00"
        },
        "updated": {
            "$t": "2014-10-24T21:21:43.914+07:00"
        },
        "category": [{
            "scheme": "http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#",
            "term": "Flat Design"
        }, {
            "scheme": "http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#",
            "term": "Service"
        }],
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "Blloon"
        },
        "content": {
            "type": "html",
            "$t": "<div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http:\/\/1.bp.blogspot.com\/-JChWOcR1GAo\/VEkIUDSmAbI\/AAAAAAAAAZI\/VGvhCLn9oKs\/s1600\/blloon.com-Blloon.jpeg\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"http:\/\/1.bp.blogspot.com\/-JChWOcR1GAo\/VEkIUDSmAbI\/AAAAAAAAAZI\/VGvhCLn9oKs\/s1600\/blloon.com-Blloon.jpeg\" \/><\/a><\/div><br \/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab quae laboriosam quidem quod, adipisci omnis nostrum blanditiis porro quam quisquam veritatis accusantium qui cumque commodi sequi fugiat consectetur nulla, illum!<br \/><br \/><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http:\/\/1.bp.blogspot.com\/-DL28zkUj9a8\/VEkIPR8tV3I\/AAAAAAAAAZE\/46ozW-aOJiw\/s1600\/chileda.org-Chileda%2B%2B%2BHelping%2Bchildren%2Bwith%2Bcognitive%2Band%2Bbehavioral%2Bchallenges.jpeg\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"http:\/\/1.bp.blogspot.com\/-DL28zkUj9a8\/VEkIPR8tV3I\/AAAAAAAAAZE\/46ozW-aOJiw\/s1600\/chileda.org-Chileda%2B%2B%2BHelping%2Bchildren%2Bwith%2Bcognitive%2Band%2Bbehavioral%2Bchallenges.jpeg\" \/><\/a><\/div><br \/><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http:\/\/3.bp.blogspot.com\/-NUAqgePVawo\/VEkJdF-KVHI\/AAAAAAAAAZk\/4WaAtc-pvzc\/s1600\/lamassu.is-Bitcoin%2BATM%2BMachine%2B%2B%2BLamassu.jpeg\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"http:\/\/3.bp.blogspot.com\/-NUAqgePVawo\/VEkJdF-KVHI\/AAAAAAAAAZk\/4WaAtc-pvzc\/s1600\/lamassu.is-Bitcoin%2BATM%2BMachine%2B%2B%2BLamassu.jpeg\" \/><\/a><\/div><br \/>"
        },
    }
});
```

It's my first post and there are three image tags inside it.

Then this is my second post and there are two image tags inside it.

```
// API callback
extract({
    "version": "1.0",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "entry": {
        "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
        "xmlns$blogger": "http://schemas.google.com/blogger/2008",
        "xmlns$georss": "http://www.georss.org/georss",
        "xmlns$gd": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005",
        "xmlns$thr": "http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0",
        "id": {
            "$t": "tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-8885963640212113245.post-7814577047467078813"
        },
        "published": {
            "$t": "2014-10-23T21:35:00.000+07:00"
        },
        "updated": {
            "$t": "2014-10-24T21:31:22.546+07:00"
        },
        "category": [{
            "scheme": "http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#",
            "term": "Charity"
        }, {
            "scheme": "http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#",
            "term": "Flat Design"
        }],
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "Chileda"
        },
        "content": {
            "type": "html",
            "$t": "<div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http:\/\/4.bp.blogspot.com\/-DL28zkUj9a8\/VEkIPR8tV3I\/AAAAAAAAAZA\/-PXPTZweu-w\/s1600\/chileda.org-Chileda%2B%2B%2BHelping%2Bchildren%2Bwith%2Bcognitive%2Band%2Bbehavioral%2Bchallenges.jpeg\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"http:\/\/4.bp.blogspot.com\/-DL28zkUj9a8\/VEkIPR8tV3I\/AAAAAAAAAZA\/-PXPTZweu-w\/s1600\/chileda.org-Chileda%2B%2B%2BHelping%2Bchildren%2Bwith%2Bcognitive%2Band%2Bbehavioral%2Bchallenges.jpeg\" \/><\/a><\/div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab quae laboriosam quidem quod, adipisci omnis nostrum blanditiis porro quam quisquam veritatis accusantium qui cumque commodi sequi fugiat consectetur nulla, illum!<br \/><br \/><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http:\/\/1.bp.blogspot.com\/-AUGcmEviNdw\/VEkKUJ9dY_I\/AAAAAAAAAZ8\/hjuKmp0x6j4\/s1600\/www.educreations.com-Educreations.jpeg\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"http:\/\/1.bp.blogspot.com\/-AUGcmEviNdw\/VEkKUJ9dY_I\/AAAAAAAAAZ8\/hjuKmp0x6j4\/s1600\/www.educreations.com-Educreations.jpeg\" \/><\/a><\/div><br \/>"
        },
    }
});
```

To install the slider, I have a plan to use [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/), and the flexslider markup look like this:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The question is, how I can extract the image source from the JSON request and then append it to flexslider markup? I understand a little about javascript, but not too expert. A jsFiddle example will help me very much (but not necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
extract = function(json){
    var html = $(json.entry.content.$t);
    html.find("img").each( function(){
       $(".flexslider .slides").append($("<li>").append(this));
    });    

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    });
}

$(window).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.prowebinspire.com/feeds/posts/default/2877822832429210498?alt=json-in-script&callback=extract",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    });
});
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajL4wj6z/)

Update: Added ajax-request and flexslider(). 
        Updated fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajL4wj6z/4/)

Comment: It works when the JSON inserted in the document (http://jsfiddle.net/ajL4wj6z/1/), but not work when the JSON called as external resources (http://jsfiddle.net/ajL4wj6z/2/)

Comment: I have 5 posts in my homepage, so there is 5 JSON request in one document. The script work as expected, but it append the last JSON request (5th JSON) to all posts. I change your code in `$.ajax url` to `url: jsonurl,` to make the URL source dynamic, then I add this code in each post: `<script> var jsonurl="/feeds/posts/default/2877822832429210498?alt=json-in-script&callback=extract",jsonid="2877822832429210498"</script>`. Note that `2877822832429210498` are post ID and are generated automatically by blogger system. How to make your script to append the right JSON to right post based on ID?

Comment: @AnderMorales you have 5 different sliders? heres how to call function with id: http://jsfiddle.net/ajL4wj6z/5/

Comment: still same problem... can we apply the slider to post with ID `2877822832429210498` that take data from JSON `2877822832429210498`, and then apply another slider to post with ID `SOMEID` that take data from JSON `SOMEID` too? It's not a problem to apply the script five times (one for each post with unique ID).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your json is stored in a variable named `data` (*after the ajax request*), then

```
data.entry.content.$t
```

refers to the actual html string of that post.

You can create an in-memory element and insert that HTML to it so you can start parsing it with jQuery DOM traversing methods.

```
var dummy = $('<div/>', { html = data.entry.content.$t }),
    images = dummy.find('img');
```

To insert those in the slider (*if the flexslider works with dynamically appended content*) do

```
images.each(function(){
  $('<li/>', {html: this}).appendTo('.flexslider .slides');
});
```